# Hive: split string using regex

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I have a string of words that are `::` delimited. How can I use the `Hive` `UDF` `regexp_extract()` to extract words from the string?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with invoketheshells answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
regexp_extract('2foa1fa::12hjk','^(\\w.*)\\:{2}(\\w.*)$',1) as word1
```

OUTPUT: `2foa1fa`

```
regexp_extract('2foa1fa::12hjk','^(\\w.*)\\:{2}(\\w.*)$',2) as word2
```

OUTPUT: `12hjk`

- ^      anchors to the beginning of the string
- The \\w    looks for a word character  and  .* means any number of times
- The  \\:{2} looks for two : in a row (this is your :: delimiter)
- $      anchors the string to the end of the string
- specifying the third parameter in regexp_extract extracts the indexed (pattern)

Now just stick your column name in the place of the string literal and you should be good to go.

You can also use a split function creating an array and then query by the array location as well. Which will look something like this:

```
select my_array[2] from 
    (select split('2foa1fa::12hjk','\\::') as my_array from my_table) b;
```

OUTPUT: `12hjk`