# How to use String split function on multi-delimiter strings in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

My string data is like below.

```
data = 'ABCD/~DEFG/~HJKL/~MNOP'
```

I tried with below query

```
select split(data,'[/~]')[1] from test_table;
```

**Expected output:
ABCD
Original output:
[SPACES]**

When i tried the same query with index [2] its working.

```
select split(data,'[/~]')[2] from test_table;
```

**Expected output:
DEFG
Original output:
DEFG**

My observation:
Its working fine for every EVEN index number like 0,2,4..
and it is populating spaces for ODD index numbers like 1,3,5..

Can someone help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use split as: `split('\\/~')`:

```
hive> select split('word1/~word2/~word3','\\/~')[0] as word1;
word1
```

---

Also, 
check my answer: [load-data-into-hive-with-custom-delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829247/2079249) using `MultiDelimitSerDe` 
 and other option using `regexp_extract`: [hive-split-string-using-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31352133/2079249)

---

Examples: there should be some easy regex to achieve this but I came up with this after following [example from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497090/hive-regexp-extract-weirdness):

```
hive> select regexp_extract('word1/~word2/~word3','^(\\w.*)\\/~(\\w.*)$',2) as word3;
word3

hive> select regexp_extract('word1/~word2/~word3','^(?:([^/~]+)\\/~?){1}',1) as word1;
word1

hive> select regexp_extract('word1/~word2/~word3','^(?:([^/~]+)\\/~?){2}',1) as word2;
word2
```